# I have never seen her wear trousers. Why not use ‘she’ instead of ‘her’?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

I see a sentence in my book: I have never seen her wear trousers.

And I think we should use she instead of ‘her’.
Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

No.  In English the pronoun in this position takes the object form "her", "him" "me" or "them".

This is used in all similar verbs of sensation like "hear" or "feel"

> I heard him eat a crisp.
>
> I felt them creep up behind me.

It is also used with an -ing verb:

> I saw her playing tennis.
>
> She must have seen me coming

On the other hand, with a "that" clause, the pronoun goes back to the subject form.

> I saw that she was eating.

Even when "that" is omitted.

> I saw she was eating.

So to compare these sentences

> I saw her eating  {a fact of what I saw}
>
> I saw she was eating  {I learn what she was doing}

In context:

> Have you seen Jo? — Yes, I saw her eating with her friends.
>
> Have you spoken to Jo? No. I saw she was eating with her friends, and I didn't want to embarrass her. I'll talk to her when she is alone.

Comment: Is this right: I saw that she was eating?  Can I say: I saw she was eating?

Comment: @Y.zeng: yes. You can often omit the complementiser "that" .